# Full Calendar jquery defined rows in week view

Tags: jquery, web, calendar, fullcalendar

Hi I was wondering if it was possible to use full calendar to display a weekly calendar with multiple rows for calendar planning against persons, by day and not time. The link to the image below explains what I am looking to accomplish.

http://s13.postimg.org/b0vphhqrb/10_9_2013_2_05_12_PM.png

I cannot seem to find any web solution to fit my needs and Full Calendar seems to be the closest.

UPDATE
Apparently Full Calendar calls the 'times'(9:30) on the left a slot. Another way to put this, is there a way to define a custom slot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for a "resource view". There isn't anything officially available for this, but it's a popular request and there are some implementations out there.

This is the best one I've seen: http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/ (code [here](https://github.com/jarnokurlin/fullcalendar))

Googling or searching SO for "fullcalendar resource view" can provide more leads. Your best best is to find something that mostly works and then modify it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object. Good luck with it.